# How to set timeout before response in kafka properties in java language as i need to mock webhook api message pushing to queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, webhooks

How to set timeout before response in kafka properties in java language as i need to mock webhook api message pushing with timeout before response = 60 sec

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
    
    public class AsyncConsumer {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            // Properties to connect Kafka
    
            Properties prop = new Properties();
    
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "1");
            //prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.de, "60000");
            
            
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_DOC, "60000");
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_DOC, "60000");
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig., "60000");
    
            // prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
            // prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "60000");
            // prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_DOC, "60000");
            // prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
            // prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
            prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "70000");
    
            // kafka Consumer
            KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, Object>(prop);
    
            // Subscription of kafka
    
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("TestTopic"));
    
            // read data from kafka
    
            while (true) {
    
                ConsumerRecords<String, Object> record = consumer.poll(60000);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> records : record) {
    
                    System.out.println("Key :" + records.key() + "\n" + "Value :" + records.value() + "\n" + "partition :"
                            + records.partition() + "\n" + "offset :" + records.offset() + "\n" + "topic :"
                            + records.topic() + "\n" + "timestamp :" + records.timestamp() + "\n");
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

```
    package com.matchmove.Performance.kafka.tests;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
    
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Logger;
    import com.matchmove.tests.ASYNCpostWebhookTest;
    
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;
    
    public class AsyncProducer {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            // Properties to connect Kafka
    
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            
            prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
            prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
            prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
            //prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_DOC,"60000");
            //prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG,"60000");
            //prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"60000");
            //prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"60000");
            prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
            
            
            
            //creating producer
             KafkaProducer<String,Object> producer=new KafkaProducer<String,Object>(prop);
             
            
           for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
              
               ProducerRecord<String,Object> record=new ProducerRecord<String, Object>("TestTopic",ASYNCpostWebhookTest.PostAsynPerformance());
               producer.send(record);
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               
              System.out.println(record);
           }
            
           producer.close();
    
    
    
    
        }
    }
```

```
        package com.matchmove.tests;
    
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import com.matchmove.utilities.RandomStringGeneration;
    
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import io.restassured.response.Response;
    import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
    
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    
    import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.cli.Main;
    import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
    import com.matchmove.helpingfiles.*;
    
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    
    public class ASYNCpostWebhookTest {
    
        protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ASYNCpostWebhookTest.class.getName());
    
        Faker fake = new Faker();
    
        static HashMap<String, Object> AsyncBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        static HashMap<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        public static RequestSpecification httpRequest;
        public static Response response;
    
        public static String generatedString = RandomStringGeneration.randomstring();
    
        public static String generatedNumber = RandomStringGeneration.number();
    
        public static String PostAsynPerformance() {
    
            RestAssured.baseURI = "https://platform-svc-webhook.kops.matchmove-beta.com";
            httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
    
            AsyncBody.put("trace_id", "Amit Bhalla data " + generatedNumber);
            AsyncBody.put("service_name", "fast");
            AsyncBody.put("event_name", "OPENLOOP_DECLINED_PROGRAM_POS_LIMITS_BREACHED");
            AsyncBody.put("push_message_to_queue_count", 10);
            message.put("message", "Testing for Async by Amit Bhalla " + generatedNumber);
            AsyncBody.put("event_data", message);
    
            response = given().header("Authorization",
                    "Basic ZW5YZTVFMnhSU3Z6RnFCWUZvOEF2ejV2UnJsd2hEeDM6ZnNPcHp1RXE0WGFUbm0wM013YmpSS2hSYzk3TktQR2FzbjRtc1hieTB"
                            + "zQ21GYUlpZ3BZTUF3UGVUNDZrUEE3SA==")
                    .body(AsyncBody).when().post(resources.PostAsyncWebhook);
    
            // String responsebody = response.getBody().asString();
    
            String body = AsyncBody.toString();
            return body;
    
        }
    
        /*
         * public static void main(String [] args) {
         * 
         * ASYNCpostWebhookTest data=new ASYNCpostWebhookTest();
         * ASYNCpostWebhookTest.PostAsynPerformance(); }
         */
    
   }
```

Comment: Your poll duration already is a form of timeout, but it's in an infinite while loop, so what is the point of having any timeout?

Comment: I removed while(true) {} block but still not able to get delay of 60 sec ...........as i want that the 60 sec delay should be inserted explicitly at consumer side. For e.g. message requested at 1:01 pm and received at 1:02 pm..........then the delay is 1:02 -1:01 = 1 min..

Comment: Why would you want this if the data is immediately available in the topic for consumer processing? Kafka is not a batch framework, so don't force it into one

Comment: If you must aggregate data for sending it downstream to your webhook, store the data in a database (in real time), then run some scheduled query, separately, to collect that data